# What is the meaning of this message?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

Today while browsing internet using Google Chrome, I encountered this message. But after I clicked on "Close Message", Chrome was still running with no tabs closed/refreshed. So my questions are:

1. What is the meaning of this message and why did it appear?
2. Why did Chrome not close even after this message? Should I be worried?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Chrome runs it splits ([forks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29)) itself in to several processes, generally one for each running tab from what I can tell.

It is entirely possible that one of the tabs (or perhaps even a container process for Adobe Flash) crashed or performed an illegal operation and was closed in the manner you see above.

This *could* affect the other tabs, but generally would not and so Chrome itself would carry on almost as if nothing had happened.  It may be that if it was an Adobe Flash container process that crashed that it would simply be reloaded and you would have absolutely no reason to see a problem as everything would carry on regardless.

Answer (score 2):

"Close Message" probably refers to dismissing the message, rather than closing Chrome.

[DEP (Data Execution Prevention)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention) is a security feature in most modern OS. It can be reduced or [disabled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention#Configuration) but unless it happens on a regular basis then I would leave it just be. Were you running any Chrome addons when this popped up? It could have triggered it.

Comment: Well I have around 8 extensions installed apart from Adobe Flash. It has started happening today and in the last one hour happened 3 times.